# Aurelia-Bundler Cannot Fetch aurelia-router.js

Tags: gulp, aurelia

So I am working through my first aurelia-bundler gulp task.  I was following the article [here](http://blog.durandal.io/2015/09/11/bundling-aurelia-apps/) except I declared my file as a gulpfile.js instead of the bundler.js that seems to be setup in his solution (I doubt that will matter).  Regardless, when I run gulp bundle I get the following error:

```
C:\dev\Movies\src\Movies>gulp bundle
[21:13:34] Using gulpfile C:\dev\Movies\src\Movies\gulpfile.js
[21:13:34] Starting 'bundle'...
[21:13:36] 'bundle' errored after 1.68 s
[21:13:36] Error on fetch for aurelia-router.js at file:///C:/dev/Movies/src/Movies/wwwroot/aurelia-router.js
        Loading movies/edit.js
        Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\dev\Movies\src\Movies
\wwwroot\aurelia-router.js'
    at Error (native)
```

I am not sure why this would be looking in that location since these libraries are all under the jspm_packages folder.  My gulp file is setup as follows:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var bundler = require('aurelia-bundler');

var config = {
    force: true,
    packagePath: '.',
    bundles: {
        "wwwroot/appbundle":{
            includes:[
              'app', 'main', 'about/**', 'movies/**', 'resources/**',
              'aurelia-bootstrapper',
              'aurelia-framework',
              'aurelia-router',
              'aurelia-http-client',
              'aurelia-validation'
            ],
            options:{
                inject: true
            }
        }
    }
};

gulp.task('bundle', function () {
    return bundler.bundle(config);
});

gulp.task('unbundle', function () {
    return bundler.unbundle(config);
});
```

Any thoughts why this is happening, I even removed all the aurelia libraries from the config and I still get the aurelia-router.js error?!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently the config.js file was missing an alias for aurelia-router.  Adding the alias below allowed the bundler gulp task to complete as desired:

```
"aurelia-router": "github:aurelia/router@0.14.1",
```

Comment: I found something similar too. It is probably because, originally, your app included router as a dependency of one of the other modules rather than being explicitly added to the app. Therefore the bundler didn't see it as a top level module that could be included. However if you were to run 'jspm install aurelia-router' then this would add it (similar to putting it in the config manually) and it would probably work. I think...

Comment: To anyone else reading this, this means that your Router (or other dependency with similar issue) was not properly added into the JSPM dependencies section. If you are currently using a version of JSPM higher than 10.16.19, you will run into issues with dependencies not being mapped on config.js properly. Something to be aware of.